# Eliminating false solutions in an inverse trig equation

Tags: trigonometry

For an equation like $\cos^{-1}x-\sin^{-1}x=\frac{\pi}{3}$, when I solve it like
$$\sin(\cos^{-1}x-\sin^{-1}x)=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$(\sin\cos^{-1}x)(\cos\sin^{-1}x)-(\sin\sin^{-1}x)(\cos\cos^{-1}x)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}\times\sqrt{1-x^2}-x^2=\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$$
$$\therefore x^2=\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}$$
What is the reasoning behind why I only take the positive root?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first step is to take the $\sin$ of both sides. But this step can introduce extraneous solutions. For instance, if I start from $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$ and take the $\sin$ of both sides, I get $\sin x=\frac12$; but this equation is also true for e.g $x=\frac{5\pi}{6}$.

So when you arrive at $x=\pm\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt3}{4}}$, you have to check both solutions, and you find that only the positive solution satisfies the original equality.

(And in fact if you take the negative solution, the left-hand side evaluates to $\frac{2\pi}{3}$, whose $\sin$ is likewise $\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$.)

Comment: So the only way is to check? Because in an exam I don't think I'm allowed to say "by calculator" as a reason for eliminating a solution. Is there some line that I can write about quadrants or something?

Comment: @Quippy, here you can say "If $x$ is negative, then $\cos^{-1}(x)\ge\pi/2$ and $\sin^{-1}(x)\le 0$, so the left-hand side is at least $\pi/2$."